# Printing php page with various values

Tags: php, mysql, printing

I have a php page that gets values from my database called `print.php` which I use to display and print the values from my database.

`print.php?id=100` loads the page with values from the database that has the id 100. each record on my database has a field to store the date the record was created. As for now I visit `print.php?id=100`, `print.php?id=101`, `print.php?id=102`, `print.php?id=103` and so on to print the same page but with various values.

Is there a way for me to create a button which does this automatically?

This button should grab all records that have the current date and print all those pages.

Sorry for being unclear.

My print.php page echos values from my database like this:
Id: `<?php echo $info['id']; ?>`
Name: `<?php echo $info['name']; ?>`
Date: `<?php echo $info['date']; ?>`
Gender: `<?php echo $info['gender']; ?>`

So for example visiting print.php?id=100 loads these values:
Id: 100
Name: John
Date: 2013-04-09
Gender: Male

Cisiting print.php?id=101 loads these values:
Id: 101
Name: Sarah
Date: 2013-04-09
Gender: Female

and so on.

When visiting each page I hit CTRL+P to print that information.

Instead of doing this manually (visiting each page and sending it to printer) I would like to have a script which grabs all the records of current date and sends it to my printer.

Comment: you could use ?id=100,101,102 and use split the ?id= at every instance of , and echo values from there?

Comment: your question still not clear. Can you please elaborat it.

Comment: You have to send `date` instead of `id`. For example `print.php?date=09-04-2013` and in your PHP script you can use this date in your SQL query, i.e. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '$date'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to archieve, but I think you want a form like this:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="100"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

this would redirect the user to `print.php?id=100` or with the value given in the textbox

EDIT:

What I read from the comments on the question is this what you want to archieve:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="date" value="<?=date('yyyy-mm-dd');?>"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

this would show a form with a textfield with the date of today printed in.

then you should make a query and fetch it like this:

```
$date = check_date($_GET['date']);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM values WHERE date="'.$date.'"';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // print row
    }
}
```

the function `check_date()` is up to you to create, this checks if the text is a valid date to make sure nobody can hack your database

Comment: I read the question again and I'll edit it my answer to your more specific needs

Comment: If only current date will be used then it's not necessary to pass a date from the form at all. `CURDATE()` in the query will do the work.

Comment: I know, but though the question is not very clear and I want to give the asker the flexibility of putting a date in himself.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand (it's not very clear) you want records for a specified date. Then you have to send a parameter for that date but not a single record id.

So, you can send a date with `print.php?date=09-04-2013` for example and in you PHP script your query would be:

```
$date = $_GET['date']; // validate it

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '$date'";

// fetch result

// print with a foreach loop as you like
```

Or if you want the current date only you don't need to pass a parameter at all. Just use `CURDATE()` if your date field contains only the date or `NOW()` if it contains date and time:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = CURDATE()";

// fetch result

// print with a foreach loop as you like
```

More: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Still couldn't understand whether you have a problem with the HTML or with the PHP part. 
If you are asking just for html forms and how to create a button you can check here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

It's pretty simple to understand.

Comment: In the second code block the variable `$_GET['date']` isn't needed if you only use `CURDATE()` ;)